# experimental optimizeCss causes CPU 100%

Tags: next.js

I'm wondering why enabling the `optimizeCss` consumes a lot of CPU 100% with less than 100 HTTP requests. Disabling this feature improves the performance x10.
Any ideas or solutions?

```
experimental: {
    optimizeCss: true // 100% CPU
  }
```

Comment: What version of Nextjs are you using?

Comment: @H9ee I'm using Version 12

Comment: you dont need use this , next 12 have auto optimiz css, but you need custome check  this link : https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config and https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler